# elastic search cluster behind azure public load balancer

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I am trying to setup ES cluster behind azure load balancer /cloud service.
The cluster is 3 node with no specific data/client/master node settings. By default 2 nodes are elected as master and 1 as data node.

As the request (create/update/search) from application comes to azure load balancer on 9200 port which load balanced for all 3 vms the request can go to any vm.

Will master node be able to serve the requests ?

Many article says that you don't need load balancer for ES cluster  just use client node but then it becomes single point of failure as azure vm can go down any point of time. so load balancing is required mainly for high availability from infrastructure point of view.

Please suggest cluster setup and which nodes (data or client) to be put behind load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ES Master node can also serve the request when it is auto elected master.
all 3 nodes can be set as master=true as well data=true and put behind load balancer.